# How to prevent event propagation for "Enter" key press in ag-grid-react cellEditor component?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

My question primarily revolves around [this statement](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/) in the docs w.r.t. the react component:

> **cellEditor Params**
>
> **onKeyDown** Callback to tell grid a key was pressed - useful to pass
> control key events (tab, arrows etc) back to grid - however you do not
> need to call this as the grid is already listening for the events as
> they propagate. This is only required if you are preventing event
> propagation.

I understand that the cellEditor params exist as the props being passed to the react version of the component but I can't seem to find how to attach to **onKeyDown** as specified in the docs. In my constructor for my cellEditor the onKeyDown function exists and matches the `onKeyDown` specified in `cellEditorParams` inside my column definition (if it exists).

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // console.log(typeof props.onKeyDown == 'function') => 'true'
}
```

But it's never reached if it simply exists in the component

```
onKeyDown(event) {
  console.log('not reached');
}
```

It does get invoked if I put `onKeyDown={this.props.onKeyDown}` inside of a top level wrapping div around my input but it still doesn't catch the "Enter" press.

I tried listening to the cell containing my custom cell editor

```
this.props.eGridCell.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  console.log(event.keyCode === 13)
})
```

Which **does capture the enter press** but it seems to unmount when enter is pressed before I can capture the final enter press inside the field? I've seen behavior where this doesn't work too so I'm very confused.

I currently have a simple cell editor *MyCellEditor* that I am trying to make focus and select the next cell when enter is pressed in addition to just tab. I already have the ability to extract the `rowIndex` and `column` properties I need from the rowRenderer at `this.props.api.rowRenderer` which I then use like:

`this.props.api.rowRenderer.moveFocusToNextCell(rowIndex, column, false, false, true);`

My issue is where to prevent the event propagation by default from the "Enter" press.

Below is my Cell Editor and the usage.

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

class MyCellEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: props.value,
    };
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.state.value;
  }

  isPopup() {
    return false;
  }

  isCancelBeforeStart() {
    return false;
  }

  afterGuiAttached() {
    const eInput = this.input;
    eInput.focus();
    eInput.select();
  }

  onKeyDown(event) {
    // Never invoked!
  }

  onChangeListener = (e) => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        ref={(c) => { this.input = c; }}
        className="ag-cell-edit-input"
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.onChangeListener} />
    );
  }
}
export default MyCellEditor;
```

Column definition:

```
columnDefs = [{
    headerName: 'CustomColumn',
    field: 'customField',
    editable: true,
    cellClass: 'grid-align ag-grid-shop-order-text',
    sortable: false,
    cellEditorFramework: MyCellEditor,
    // Do I need cellEditorParams?
    cellEditorParams: {
      // onKeyDown: (event) => console.log('does not output')
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

React:

```
<AgGridReact
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  rowData={this.props.rows}
  enableColResize="false"
  rowSelection="single"
  enableSorting="false"
  singleClickEdit="true"
  suppressMovableColumns="true"
  rowHeight="30"
  // onKeyDown also does nothing here
  onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
  onGridResize={() => console.log('grid resized')}
  onColumnResize={() => console.log('column resized')} />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@buddyp450, had exactly same problem and created an issue under ag-grid gitgub, however found workaround few minutes later, you can change key code to 13 in my example and works perfect :)

https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1300

```
export default class PATableCellEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        :
    }
    :
    afterGuiAttached() {
        // get ref from React component
        let eInput = this.refs.textField;
        :
        // Add a listener to 'keydown'
        let self = this;
        eInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            self.myOnKeyDown(event)
        });
        :
    }
    :
    // Stop propagating 'left'/'right' keys
    myOnKeyDown(event) {
        let key = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if (key === 37 ||  // left
            key === 39) {  // right
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
    :
```

Luis

Comment: Tested on 6.0.1 and 7.0.0, works on 6.0.1 and 7.0.0 but the navigation feels broken in 7.0.0. I think that's unrelated. I'm sticking with 6.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Add listener to grid containers to capture the key-down.

```
onGridReady: {(event) =>  
    event.api.gridPanel.eAllCellContainers.forEach(
        function (container) {
             container.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownFunc);
    });
}
...
```

Define the listener.

```
function keyDownFunc(e) {
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter = 13
       // TODO: Handle event
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately none of the provided answers are actually able to prevent the propagation of the native ag-grid navigation events despite stopping event propagation, immediate propagation, and preventing the default.

Somewhere in an unknown area to me with the react ag-grid the navigation elements are hijacking everything. I know this since I added a console out to the `renderedCell.ts` in the source after adding the listeners as suggested in this thread and got the renderedCell's console out before the listener's console out.

I eventually went for the simply-stupid approach of forking ag-grid and tweaking the onKeyDown:

```
case Constants.KEY_ENTER:
  // this.onEnterKeyDown();
  // Whatever makes the clients happy amirite?
  this.onTabKeyDown();
  break;
```

Answer (score 2):

From `v13.2.0` onwards, ag-grid has a `suppressKeyboardEvent` callback that can be added to the column definition to customise the default keyboard navigation. You can find the documentation and an example [here in the official docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/#suppress-keyboard-event)

Comment: I've been struggling with this, for some reason stopPropagation stops my editor from doing its function properly. So I need to use suppressKeyboardEvent, but it only gets called when navigating, params.editing is never true. I have no idea why. Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found from the documentation of ag-grid that the "grid-api" is provided by the onGridRead() callback of the React component.
The following api function can help you register an event for keyPress.

```
addEventListener(eventType, listener)
```

Try something like:

```
onGridReady = (api)=>{
    api.addEventListener('keyPress', this.keyPressEventHandlerCallback);
}

keyPressEventHandlerCallback=(e)=>{
    ...handler code here
}
```

Comment: This does not work, `grid.api.addEventListener("keydown", (ev: any) =>{ })` is not fired on a key down; and `grid.api.addGlobalListener` is not helpful for this situation. @Luis Palacios suggestion works.

Answer (score 0):

the intention is you capture the 'enter' press in you cellRenderer as follows:

```
render() {
 return (
  <input
    ref={(c) => { this.input = c; }}
    className="ag-cell-edit-input"
    type="text"
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.onChangeListener}
    onKeyDown={this.onKeyDownListener} />
);
```

then you would prevent the propagation from the onKeyDownListener. that's how it works in javascript. if something is happening different in React then I don't know :(

Comment: I believe the enter press is being captured and redirected somewhere higher up the chain. It never hits this listener.

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing is changing a line in afterGuiAttached (example LargeTextCellEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached) so that this.textarea.focus is called from a timeout.  ( I didn't look further for the source of the problem yet, but this works for me for now )

```
LargeTextCellEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function () {
        if (this.focusAfterAttached) {
            // this.textarea.focus();
            setTimeout(()=>this.textarea.focus());
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution to use the `onKeyDown` param, so basically, we prevent all the key events

```
cellEditorParams: {
  onKeyDown: () => undefined
}
```